# Conga Courier: Only Salesforce Administrators Are Receiving Conga Courier Emails

Tags: email, reporting, conga

I just installed the 30-day trial of Conga Courier in Salesforce and I've set up the workflow so that each person receives customized report information.

I've found that only Users with the System Administrator profile are receiving the emails. The reports are sending accurately with customized information, but they don't send if the user isn't an administrator. No send information is recorded for these individuals in the Activity History.

Any ideas?

Comment: N.b. Appextremes has superb phone support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Robert! I actually had to give Read access to Courier Schedule, not Recipients. Just wanted to clarify for any one who looks at this in the future!

Comment: Rochelle - you should mark this as an Answer to aid the community

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've gotten in touch with one of our Business Analysts at Conga to resolve the problem, but just wanted to drop the resolution here for future reference:

If you're using the advanced method of using workflow rules to send Courier Reports to individuals that only contain information relevant to them (records they own, records they're authorized to see, etc.), then those users will need a profile with at least "read" access to the Recipients custom object in Conga Courier.

Thanks for reaching out, and please let us know if there's anything else we can help with.

-Robert